# Column/margin misbehaving in IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

According to Browserlab, [this page](http://cubacreative.co.nz/) displays fine in everything but IE8 and under. IE6 I can certainly live without, but I'd really like to at least fix the issue in IE8.

See screen shot below illustrating the problem: It seems to me that the first column under the logo has a left-margin of 10px or so that is causing the third column to drop below.

Is this a common bug? Or do I need to post more info on the issue?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

Take div class four columns and move it just after div id content.

Then apply this style to content :

```
width:960px;
```

Then this style to four columns :

```
float:right;
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks @dav, but I am using Wordpress and would really prefer not to edit the templates if at all possible!